# How would I go about loading other page's content into a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a single page app soon. Basically, there will be many pages, just like any other site, e.g.: Home, About Us, Contact Us, Games. But the Home.cshtml page will be the main page and when you click a menu item on the homepage, for example, the About Us link, then the content from the About Us page will be loaded and displayed into the Home.cshtml page in a `div`.

How would I go about loading content into a div from an external file? I have searched online but some of the solutions look messy and not very well explained and outdated, and it leaves me wondering if that is the best way.

Comment: http://angularjs.org/

Comment: Thanks @adeneo, I had forgotten about AngularJS. I'll stick around to accept an answer, if you want to make that an answer.

Comment: [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) does the same thing, but in a mobile first approach..